# Exception caught by gesture in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile

I am making a To-do List in Flutter and I am currently studying about Routes and I experienced a problem called "Exception caught by gesture" with the description saying "Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/details", Instance of 'Note') in the _WidgetsAppState.", do anyone has any idea on how to fix the error stated above?

Here are my codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_list/details.dart';
import 'package:todo_list/note.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int number;
  final String listDescription;

  const MyApp(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      required this.number,
      required this.listDescription});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        DetailsPage.routeName: (ctx) => DetailsPage(text, listDescription),
      },
      home: CustomListTile(
        text: text,
        number: number,
        listDescription: listDescription,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int number;
  final String listDescription;

  const CustomListTile(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      required this.number,
      required this.listDescription});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, DetailsPage.routeName,
            arguments: Note(title: text, description: listDescription));
      },
      /* onTap: () {
        Widget okButton = TextButton(
          child: const Text("CLOSE"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        );

        AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
            title: Text(text),
            content: Text('This item in the list contains $listDescription'),
            actions: [
              okButton,
            ]);
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return alert;
            });
      }, */

      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("$number. $text",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    )),
                const Icon(Icons.chevron_right)
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              listDescription,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            const Divider()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'note.dart';

class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/details";
  final String text;
  final String listDescription;

  const DetailsPage(this.text, this.listDescription, {super.key});

  @override
  State<DetailsPage> createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  late Note params;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    params = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments! as Note;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget titleSection = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
                  child: Text(
                    params.title,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

    Widget buttonSection = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        _buildButtonColumn(
          color,
          Icons.edit,
          'EDIT',
        ),
        _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.delete, 'DELETE'),
      ],
    );

    Widget textSection = Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Text(
        params.description,
        softWrap: true,
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Layout for a New Screen',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          title: Text(params.title),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'lib/images/placeholder.jpg',
              width: 600,
              height: 240,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            titleSection,
            buttonSection,
            textSection,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column _buildButtonColumn(
    Color color,
    IconData icon,
    String label,
  ) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(icon, color: color),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

    /* return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(text)),
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [Text(description)],
          ),
        ));
  }
} */
```

I've tried making another Route before and it successfully worked but this time, the route I've set up required me to have an argument which is new to me therefore the error I'm experiencing is new to me and I do not have any idea on how to fix or what should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- you must use Scaffold Widget.
- this is demo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp(
    listDescription: '????',
    number: 1,
    text: 'note',
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int number;
  final String listDescription;

  const MyApp(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      required this.number,
      required this.listDescription});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        routes: {
          DetailsPage.routeName: (ctx) => DetailsPage(text, listDescription),
        },
        home: Scaffold(
          body: CustomListTile(
            text: text,
            number: number,
            listDescription: listDescription,
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int number;
  final String listDescription;

  const CustomListTile(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      required this.number,
      required this.listDescription});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, DetailsPage.routeName,
            arguments: Note(title: text, description: listDescription));
      },
      /* onTap: () {
        Widget okButton = TextButton(
          child: const Text("CLOSE"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        );

        AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
            title: Text(text),
            content: Text('This item in the list contains $listDescription'),
            actions: [
              okButton,
            ]);
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return alert;
            });
      }, */

      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("$number. $text",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    )),
                const Icon(Icons.chevron_right)
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              listDescription,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            const Divider()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/details";
  final String text;
  final String listDescription;

  const DetailsPage(this.text, this.listDescription, {super.key});

  @override
  State<DetailsPage> createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  late Note params;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    params = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments! as Note;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget titleSection = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
                  child: Text(
                    params.title,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

    Widget buttonSection = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        _buildButtonColumn(
          color,
          Icons.edit,
          'EDIT',
        ),
        _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.delete, 'DELETE'),
      ],
    );

    Widget textSection = Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Text(
        params.description,
        softWrap: true,
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Layout for a New Screen',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          title: Text(params.title),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 600,
              height: 240,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            titleSection,
            buttonSection,
            textSection,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column _buildButtonColumn(
    Color color,
    IconData icon,
    String label,
  ) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(icon, color: color),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Note {
  String title;
  String description;
  Note({required this.title, required this.description});
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, bakboem!

Comment: ??????  please confirm the answer

Comment: I mean, it still shows the same error.

Comment: @nyetlog123. we can discuss [here]{https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250922/}

Comment: It says that I need to have 20 reputation, but otherwise, I appreciate your help, bakboem!

Comment: okay, you can edit you question

Comment: Hey Bakboem, do you have another place so that we can discuss this problem? I can't fix the error. :(

Comment: canyou write code to this memo?  https://memo.onl.jp/?1eLe8WZb6i

Comment: I did write the code in the memo!

Comment: you can try it now . @c0rnelia